# Viewing Output of MATLAB Code run from Python Using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am attempting to run MATLAB functions from python. I am following the 
[MathWorks Tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-script-and-function-from-python.html). In that tutorial they specify that output from a MATLAB script can be viewed in python.  The example they give has the following code

```
% This code is in a MATLAB script called triarea.m
b = 5;
h = 3;
a = 0.5*(b.* h) % Notice that there is no semicolon to suppress output.
```

The python portion:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.triarea(nargout=0)
```

The python script is supposed to print

```
a =

    7.5000
```

This works perfectly when running it as a normal python script (for example, using PyCharm). However, nothing is printed when this python code is run using Jupyter notebook.

How does one get the correct output when running the python code using Jupyter notebook?

So far, I have tried specifying standard out (as suggested in [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/redirect-standard-output-and-error-to-python.html)).  Namely my python code now reads

```
import io
out = io.StringIO()
eng.triareaf(nargout=0, stdout=out)
```

However, I still am not able to get the correct output. I am using Python 3.5, MATLAB R2017a, Jupyter version 4.4.0 and Windows 10.

Comment: No idea why it is happening. Probably that's how they made it. Btw the second example in the [linked](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-script-and-function-from-python.html) MATLAB doc-page does what you want

Comment: It doesn't quite do what I want. The second example requires that the Matlab function returns the value I want to print.  This also means that I can't see output from a Matlab script, because scripts don't have return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have the terminal open (i.e. the one in which the Jupyter Server is running) you will find there the output you are expecting.

Btw, this is not a solution but just a workaround ... still looking for a way to make the terminal output appear directly in the notebook.